# React native - Not able to perform any file system operation using react-native-fs

Tags: android, react-native, scoped-storage, react-native-fs

Suddenly after changing target SDK version to 30 all the file system operations using `react-native-fs` like `mkdir`, `moveFile`, `copyFile` etc stopped working on `react-native` android app for android version 11. I'm aware of new `scoped storage` introduced in android 10 and was using `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` flag to keep using the legacy storage. But this flag is not respected on android 11 so is there any way I can still use all the file system operation using `react-native-fs`? I saw a bunch of open issues related to this on their repo, but no clear solution is mentioned. So reaching out for any help here.

Any help on how I can continue to use all the above-mentioned fs operations on android 11 and target SDK 30 is very appreciated.

**Othe details,**
`react-native-fs` version 2.11.17 
`react-native` version 0.59.5 
targetSdkVersion : 30 
`requestLegacyExternalStorage` is set to true

Comment: @OtaniShuzo I ended up using the app's storage for managing the media.